# How to use AlarmManager to stop GPS updates (removeUpdates)

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am working on an app where the user sets a specified time range, say one hour of the day, where I want to use GPS to monitor their location. This is basically like a location based reminder app but with a specific purpose.
My issue is how to start and stop the GPS at a specified time. Currently I am using AlarmManager using the start/end times to create a broadcast. This broadcast takes me to the "MyBroadcastReceiver" class. The problem is the removeUpdates isn't stopping the GPS. I assume this is because everytime the broadcast receiver is called I am creating a new LocationManager. So with the "stop" status in my code I am just sending the "removeUpdates" to the more recently created locationManager, instead of the previously created locationManager.

I am open to reworking the entire app if the AlarmManager isn't the correct way of accomplishing this. I intend in the long run to use the info given by the user to have this select time of day to repeat daily and check for GPS location. So I will never be sure the app is going to be running when the updates are needed.
Please help I have been working and searching for days.

```
    public class ASPActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        final TimePicker startTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.startTime);
        final TimePicker endTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.endTime);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();               

                 startCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startTime.getCurrentHour());
                 startCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                 startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startTime.getCurrentMinute());

                 endCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, endTime.getCurrentHour());
                 endCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                 endCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, endTime.getCurrentMinute());

                Intent intent = new Intent(ASPActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
                Intent endIntent = new Intent(ASPActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

                intent.putExtra("startHour", Integer.toString(startTime.getCurrentHour()));
                intent.putExtra("startMinute", Integer.toString(startTime.getCurrentMinute()));
                intent.putExtra("action", "start");
                endIntent.putExtra("endHour", Integer.toString(endTime.getCurrentHour()));
                endIntent.putExtra("endMinute", Integer.toString(endTime.getCurrentMinute()));
                endIntent.putExtra("action", "stop");

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        ASPActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
                PendingIntent endPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        ASPActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 234324244, endIntent, 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                AlarmManager endAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,startCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                endAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,endCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), endPendingIntent);

            } //onClick
        }); //view Onclick listener
    } //onCreate end



public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    //Calendar mStartCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(); 
        LocationManager locationManager = null;
        LocationListener locationListener = null;
        String action = "";
        action = extras.getString("action");
        System.out.println("status = " + action);

        if (locationManager == null) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();    
        }

        if (action.equals("start")) {
            System.out.println("Hit the start status");
            //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            //LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(); 
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 1, locationListener);

        } else if (action.equals("stop")) {
            System.out.println("Hit the else status");
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }


    }



    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("Loc Changed");
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, never mind this question. I decided to create a back ground service to handle this. This approach seems to be going much smoother.